# When minting NFTs on opensea to the polygon network, is there a way to actually use my own address?

Tags: metamask, nft, polygon, opensea

When minting NFTs on https://opensea.io to the polygon network, is there a way to actually use my own address?

Even if I have MetaMask connected to the polygon network, it seems that opensea uses its own addresses to create the NFTs.  I can see on polygonscan.com that my wallet address is included in the logs in the "data" or "topics" fields, rather than the "from" or "to" addresses.

I want to use the polygonscan.com APIs to find my transactions programmatically.  Like the following.

https://api.polygonscan.com/apis

"Get a list of "ERC721 - Token Transfer Events" by Address"
**EXAMPLE URL:**  https://api.polygonscan.com/api?module=account&action=tokennfttx&address=0x6975be450864c02b4613023c2152ee0743572325&startblock=0&endblock=999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

The problem is that since opensea is not using my address, but rather using its own address, I don't have a way to find them.

Without having my own address, polygonscan would need to support an API call that let me search for transactions based on the log contents.  It doesn't appear they have such a function.

Comment: Have you signed the tx and paid for it? or you just signed without paying fees.

Answer (score 0):

If on opensea, you transfert the NFT to an other of your address, you will see the NFT on polygonscan. I didn't found an other way to do